# using -gt 1MB doesn't work, where is my mistake ? Powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I just wanted to build a small script which displays all files inside a folder (recursively) which are bigger than x MB. Somehow it shows me all files in that folder.
my script is here, can someone find the mistake ?

```
Param(
  [string]$targetfolder
  [string]$sizeinmb
)

function getfilesbigger 
{
$colItems =  (get-childitem  "$targetfolder" -recurse | where {$_.length -gt $sizeinmbMB } | tee-object -variable allfiles | measure-object -property length -sum)
$allfiles | foreach-object {write-host $_.FullName ("{0:N2}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB)) "MB" -ForegroundColor "green" }
write-host "Collected all files bigger than $sizeinmb MB from folder $targetfolder " -foregroundcolor "darkgreen"
"Number of files: "+ $colItems.count + [Environment]::NewLine + "Size of all files "+"{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB" 
}

getfilesbigger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where {$_.length -gt $sizeinmbMB}
```

`$sizeinmbMB` is `$null` - it hasn't been set. I think you're trying to pass `1` into the function and then append `MB` to the end of it, but string concatenation doesn't work this way.

Pass the *actual* size into the function (don't make this a "script", make it a reusable function that you can put somewhere for future use, like your own module), as an integer (if you use `1MB`, it will be expanded automatically), when you call it.

```
function Get-FilesBigger {
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [ValidateScript({test-path -path $_ -pathtype container})]
    [string]$Path,
    [int]$MinFileSize
)
    $colItems = get-childitem  -path $Path -recurse | where-object {$_.length -gt $MinFileSize } | tee-object -variable allfiles | measure-object -property length -sum;
    $allfiles | foreach-object {write-Verbose $($_.FullName + ("{0:N2}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB)) + "MB") };
    "Collected all files bigger than " + $MinFileSize/1MB + "MB from folder $Path ";
    "Number of files: "+ $colItems.count + [Environment]::NewLine + "Size of all files "+"{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB" ;
}

Get-FilesBigger -Path YOURPATH -MinFileSize 1MB -Verbose;
```

Comment: yep, you are right. I found out myself as well and changed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you forgot to multiply $sizeinMB by 1MB before you did the file length comparison.

Comment: i changed the varible to $size  and removed the MB stuff. so now i provide the varible like 1MB   and it's working fine. Thank you for the fast help.

Answer (score 1):

Your $sizeinmbMB should be $sizeinmb*1MB

Comment: when i hardcode 10MB as value, it's working. My syntax is wrong there i guess. always had trouble when i have to put a variable into something haha.